# Is it possible to assign a property of a class assigning it to the instance of that class?

Tags: c#

To further explain: i have a class let's say A, with a property of type let's say X; what i would like to do is to be able to instantiate A somewhere and assign the attribute using the instance without accessing the property itself or using methods, and possibly doing some other operation. Something like this:

```
public class A 
{
    private X _inside; //it actually can be public also
    private DateTime _timeStamp;

    public A() {X = new X();}
}

A anInstance = new A();

X aParameter = new X();

anInstance = aParameter
```

`aParameter` should be set to the `_inside` property of `anInstance`, while also assign `DateTime.UtcNow` to `_timeStamp`. Is it possible to do so? I am aware that doing so through a method or `get` and `set` is way easier, i'd get the same result and is possibly more efficient, but i would like to do so. 
Also, I don't know if this thing has a specific name, therefore this question may be a duplicate; I am highlighting this because i had a problem with circular headers once but i didn't know that they were called so and my question was marked as a duplicate (not an english native seaker), which is not a problem as long as pointing we have an answer.

Anyway, thanks in advance!

**Edit** lexicon fixed as suggested in the comments

Comment: No, you can't do that without accessing the  field itself or using methods.

Comment: Why would you want to assign fields this way?

Comment: Could please explain a little bit more the background because this is not possible. There are options for assigning values for example defining an Interface or using Reflection but this produce a bunch of overhead and it will not work like you wish.

Comment: @Sweeper I don' t actually need it, but I had to switch from a type Mat (OpenCV) to a custom type to keep some timestamps together with the frame i use, and i didn't want to go through the whole script to manually change every mat to my type. Also, i would like to use my type exactly like a Mat, but with a timestamp. Not sure if this makes sense, i am not an expert.

Comment: @Kinimod last comment

Comment: Sounds like inheritance. You have your class which has all properties from the base class 'Mat' and you like to add an additionally one '_timeStamp'. Correct?

Comment: Do you actually mean "Property" or do you mean "member/field" Also please don't use global variables. Instead declare X as a static member of your class.

Comment: perhaps you could overload the assignment operator? works in c++. I think. In any case what's the problem writing `instance.member = value;`? Edit - nope: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator#operator-overloadability

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking for is similar to VB classic's default properties<sup>1</sup>. Imagine that C# (and .NET in general) had adopted this concept, and that we're allowed to declare one<sup>2</sup>:

```
//Not legal c#
public class A 
{
    public default A _inside {get;set; }
    private DateTime _timeStamp;

    public A() {}
}
```

It's perfectly legal for classes to have properties of their own types, and introducing restrictions just for these default properties to avoid the problems I'm about to talk about are worse than disallowing the existence of these default properties<sup>3</sup>.

So you now have the code:

```
A anInstance = new A();

A aParameter = new A();

anInstance = aParameter;
```

Pop quiz - what does line 3 do? Does it assign `_inner`? Of does it reassign `anInstance`?

VB classic solved this issue by having two *different* forms of assignment. `Set` and `Let`. And it was a frequent source of bugs (`Option Explicit` being off by default didn't help here either).

When .NET was being designed, the designers of both C# and VB.Net looked at this and said "nope". You can have [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) (c#)/[default properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property) (VB.Net) but they have to have additional parameters:

```
public class A 
{
    private Dictionary<int,A> _inner = new Dictionary<int,A>();
    public A this[int i] {
      get { return _inner[i]; }
      set { _inner[i] = value; }
    }
    private DateTime _timeStamp;

    public A() {}
}
```

And now we can disambiguate the different assignments in a straightforward manner:

```
A anInstance = new A();

A aParameter = new A();

anInstance = aParameter;

anInstance[1] = aParameter;
```

Lines 3 and 4 are, respectively, reassigning the reference and reassigning the property value.

<sup>1</sup>VB.Net does have default properties but, as discussed later, they're not precisely the same as [VB classic's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/h7bfkxc1(v=vs.90)).

<sup>2</sup>Note that we can't assign it an instance in the constructor now - that would lead to a stack overflow exception since constructing any instance of A would require constructing an additional instance of A which would require constructing an additional instance of A which would...

<sup>3</sup>A concrete example of this would be a `Tree` class that has subtrees and a `SubTree` class that inherits from `Tree` and has a `Parent` property of tree. If that were the "default property" for the `SubTree` class you'd encounter these same property/reference assignment issues discussed lower down if trying to assign a parent of a subtree of a subtree.

Which basically means that you have to disallow default properties of both the actual type in which it's declared and any type to which it's implicitly convertible, which includes all types in its inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I'll try something like this then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about inheritance?

```
public class A : X
{
    private DateTime _timeStamp;

    public A() : base() {}
}

A anInstance = new A();

X aParameter = new X();

anInstance = (A)aParameter;
```

Comment: Don't you need an explicit cast there? Moreover, is it safe to do so and will it work in reverse?